# webkit_server installed but cannot find in script

Tags: python, pip, dryscrape

I have installed webkit-server and dryscrape - but when I run a script I get an error when using a dryscrape function. The error is as follows:

"No such file or directory: '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/webkit_server'"

However, when trying to install webkit_server, I get:

Requirement already satisfied: webkit_server in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages (1.0)

To show I already installed it, see link image.

Suggestions from my side are:

1. There is a difference between webkit_server and webkit-server?
2. Webkit_server is in the wrong place and can't be found by dryscrape?

I tried to install both using gitclone - same error

Any suggestions would be useful.

[List of pip3 installed packages includes webkit-server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8m8IB.png)

Comment: *1. There is a difference between `webkit_server` and `webkit-server`?* Not much. `webkit_server` is a directory name spelled with an underscore because python doesn't allow dashes in package names (dash is interpreted as minus). `webkit-server` is a name of the distribution. If you go to https://pypi.org/project/webkit_server/ (underscore!) PyPI will redirect you to webkit-server.

Comment: *2. Webkit_server is in the wrong place and can't be found by dryscrape?* That you have to investigate. Start with `ls -lAF /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/webkit_server*` and `pip3 show -f webkit-server` to list files in the distribution.